# Intellisense-Errors shown in Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I've recently installed the Visual Studio 2019 Update to the Verison 16.7.12.

Since then I get all Intellisense-Errors displayed in the Editor as errors.

For example the following method is marked as error:

```
public override async Task<bool> Save()
{
  return true;
}
```

The message says that this method has no await in it, but I have to implement it that way because it comes from an abstract base-class.

How can I disable the intellisense-error in the editor?

Comment: 16.9 was released yesterday, did you update to that version to see if the issue was fixed?

Answer (score 0):

My test environment is **VS2019 Community 16.8.6**

First, you should make sure that you did not treat warnings as errors. What you described is a real warning.

[image]

**If** it is an error, you should right-click on the project **Properties**-->**Build**-->select **Treat warnings as errors** to `None`.

**Further**, to suppress this warning, you should also set the **Warning level** to `0` or type `CS1998` into **suppress warning** under Project **Properties**-->**Build**-->**Errors and Warnings**

[image]

**Then**, it is missing:

[image]

Comment: Ok. This solves this type of message. But I have other CS-Messages. Do I have to supress all? I've just created a new Solution and there the CS-Messages are not displayed as errors.

Comment: The error message suggests you have to use `await`, if you use await or fix the warning, it will never happen. But if you still already `change treat as errors` to `none`, warning level to `0` and still face the errors, then they are real errors or your current project has broken. Please try these: close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder. Then, restart project to check it.

Comment: Did you mean that you have tried all my steps and the project still has some errors? Could you please share a pic with that?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know.